# Reusable summary_fields getter Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a couple of Time datatypes in my `summary_fields` array that I'd like to modify with the same getter method, but it doesn't seem possible to pass properties to them. My original thought was:

```php
class BusinessHour extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(9)',
        'Day' => 'Enum("Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday", "Monday")',
        'Open' => 'Time',
        'Close' => 'Time',
        'Closed' => 'Boolean'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Day' => 'Day',
        'OpenClose(Open)' => 'Open',
        'OpenClose(Close)' => 'Close'
    );

    public function getOpenClose($val) {
        if($val == FALSE) {
             return "Closed";
        }else {
             return $val;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I can extend the Time datatype and use it like this:

```php
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Open.OpenClose' => 'Open',
    'Close.OpenClose' => 'Close'
);
```

But is this the right way to about this?

Comment: What exactly is your use-case? Do you need to display "Close" when there's no time set, and the actual time value in all other cases?

Comment: That's what I'm aiming for. I'd like to avoid having to write two separate functions for Open and Close that do the same thing

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do. You seem to have an Open and Close time, but what should be displayed in the GridField? Can you make an example?

Comment: I've updated the question with a bit more code. If Open and Close are unset I want the GridField to say Closed in those columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you add the desired functionality via Extension to the Time DBField. Your extension could be something like:

```
class TimeExtension extends Extension
{
    public function OpenClose(){
        $val = $this->owner->getValue();
        return $val ? $val : 'Closed';
    }
}
```

Then you add the extension via YAML (eg. in `_config.yml`)

```
Time
  extensions:
    - TimeExtension
```

You should then be able to use something like this as your `summary_fields`:

```
private static $summary_fields = [
    'Open.OpenClose' => 'Open',
    'Close.OpenClose' => 'Close'
];
```

Comment: That's what I'll go with then. It just made me fee dirty to extend the DBField for an edge case like that